# Using Cursor and queries to populate data from database into ListView

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview, cursor

I'll start but saying there are no errors, I simply don't know how to code this.
I have a database containing one table, in it 4 columns and 30 rows.

This is my code to copy the database (It's static) from the assets folder:
My DBHandler class:

```
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static String TAG = "DataBaseHelper"; // Tag just for the LogCat
                                                // window
// destination path (location) of our database on device
private static String DB_PATH = "";
private static String DB_NAME = "CookbookDB";// Database name
private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;
private final Context mContext;

public DBHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);// 1? its Database Version
    DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
    this.mContext = context;
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    // If database doesn't exists copy it from the assets

    boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();
    try {
        if (!mDataBaseExist) {

            copyDataBase();
            Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase database created");
        }
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        this.close();
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");

    }

}

// Check that the database exists here: /data/data/your
// package/databases/DaName
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
    // Log.v("dbFile", dbFile + "   "+ dbFile.exists());
    return dbFile.exists();
}

// Copy the database from assets
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
    int mLength;
    while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer)) > 0) {
        mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
    }
    mOutput.flush();
    mOutput.close();
    mInput.close();
}

// Open the database, so we can query it
public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    // Log.v("mPath", mPath);
    mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
    // mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null,
    // SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
    return mDataBase != null;
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (mDataBase != null)
        mDataBase.close();
    super.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

My DataAdapter class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;

public class DataAdapter {
protected static final String TAG = "DataAdapter";

private final Context mContext;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
private DBHandler mDbHelper;

public DataAdapter(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    mDbHelper = new DBHandler(mContext);
}

public DataAdapter createDatabase() throws SQLException {
    try {
        mDbHelper.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException mIOException) {
        Log.e(TAG, mIOException.toString() + "  UnableToCreateDatabase");
        throw new Error("UnableToCreateDatabase");
    }
    return this;
}

public DataAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    try {
        mDbHelper.openDataBase();
        mDbHelper.close();
        mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "open >>" + mSQLException.toString());
        throw mSQLException;
    }
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    mDbHelper.close();
}

public Cursor getTestData() {
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM CookbookTable";

        Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
        if (mCur != null) {
            mCur.moveToNext();
        }
        return mCur;
    } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "getTestData >>" + mSQLException.toString());

        throw mSQLException;
    }
}
}
```

The implementation for the copying of the database is:

```
DataAdapter mDbHelper = new DataAdapter(getBaseContext());
mDbHelper.createDatabase();
```

I don't know how to use queries properly with Cursors. I don't even know if my open method on both classes is legit. How do I access information from my db? I managed to copy it but that's about it, from here I'm stuck. If I had just one example of copying an entire column (Lets say to use as the ListView's items' names) I think I could implement the logic behind it to my entire project.

Any help would be so much appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

To quote the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db):

> For sample apps that demonstrate how to use SQLite databases in Android, see the [Note Pad](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/index.html) and [Searchable Dictionary](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SearchableDictionary/index.html) applications.

This tutorial covers the basics: [Using the SQLite Database with ListView](http://kahdev.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/android-using-the-sqlite-database-with-listview/)